# How to distinct user on 2 column

Tags: sql, oracle

i have a table like that

create table test1(id_source number,id_cible number)

in this table i have :

```
1   2
1   3
1   4
1   5
2   1
1   6
10  4
10  4
5   1
2   6
```

In this exemple, i would have the result: 1-2-3-4-5-10(6 rows) but how did i get that with a request sql?

I need to show all distinct(user). So id_source OR id_cible from all unique user in table Test1 so i cant only do: Select distinct id_source,id_cible because he can be alone in the id_cible column only in the id_source column without be in the other column.

Rule:
The id can be only in 1 column the column like that:

```
1-2
1-3
```

so id 1 can be only in the id_source.
Or he can be in both column:

```
1-2
2-1
```

-- Exemple if i had only 1 row

```
id source =1 and id_cible = 2.
```

I am suppose to get two line .

```
line 1: id: 1
line 2: id: 2
```

-- So i start with that:

Select id_source
from test 1
union
select id_cible
from test 1.

but after, how did i count on that?

For the id (x) exemple id :1, i would know how much distinct (friend id he has) in the id_source column or in the id_cible_column.

So how did i count that with a request sql?

Thank you!

Comment: I *think* you're looking for `SELECT id_source FROM test1 UNION SELECT id_cible FROM test1`

Comment: You must try harder to explain what you need, because from what I read the question is incomprehensible.

Comment: @forpas: Haha, I had difficulties with the question, too, but understand it exactly as Shawn does.

Comment: @Abra: No. `UNION` is short for `UNION DISTINCT` and does remove duplicates.

Comment: @Abra That's what the `UNION` is for.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner so can you explain why the result should be: *1-2-3-4-5-10(6 rows)*?

Comment: @forpas: No, I can't really. I suppose they want all IDs (`"I need to show all distinct(user)"`). That the 6 is missing may be a mistake. Well, maybe, maybe not :-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% clear on what you're looking for, but if I've interpreted your question correctly you can use UNION and ORDER BY:

```
SELECT ID_SOURCE AS ID FROM TEST1
UNION
SELECT ID_CIBLE FROM TEST1
ORDER BY ID
```

which produces

```
ID
1
2
3
4
5
6
10
7 rows
```

[dbfiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=391c96969f68661eb2581bdb2f05953d)

### EDIT

After reading and re-reading the question, I *think* that what you're looking for is

```
WITH cteData AS (SELECT ID_SOURCE AS ID, ID_CIBLE AS FRIEND FROM TEST1
                 UNION
                 SELECT ID_CIBLE AS ID, ID_SOURCE AS FRIEND FROM TEST1)
SELECT ID, COUNT(FRIEND)
  FROM cteData
  GROUP BY ID
  ORDER BY ID
```

This produces the result

```
ID  COUNT(FRIEND)
1   5
2   2
3   1
4   2
5   1
6   2
10  1
7 rows
```

[dbfiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=1b114effbc4d5e9c9e6fcceb36e8f93c)